# Raft: Will term increasing all the time if partitioned?

Tags: raft

Will the partitioned server increase term all the time?
If so, I get another confusion.

Chapter 3.6 (safety) in raft paper says:

```
Raft determines which of two logs is more up-to-date by comparing the index and term of the last entries in the logs.If the logs have last entries with different terms, then the log with the later term is more up-to-date. If the logs end with the same term, then whichever log is longer is more
up-to-date.
```

It got me thinking about a scenario when one server from a partitioned network win the election because of the huge term, then causing the unconsistency. Will that happens?

Comment: I think I get the answer https://groups.google.com/g/raft-dev/c/CD8XjCmym9E/m/AvjCcb2uBwAJ

Answer (score 0):

Edit part:

When a node with larger term rejoins the cluster, that will force the current leader to step down. When a leader sends request to a follower and the follower has larger term; the follower rejects the request and the leader sees larger term; that forces the leader to step down and new election will happen.

Some raft implementations have an extra step before a follower becomes candidate - if a follower does not hear from the leader, the follower tries to connect other followers; and if there is a quorum, then the follower becomes a candidate.

---

(I read your link), and yes, an implementation may keep increasing the term; or be more practical and wait till majority is reachable - there is no point to initiate an election if no majority is available.

I decided to comment because of this line in your question "win the election because of the huge term". Long time ago, when I read raft paper (https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf), I was quite confused by the election process.

Section 5.2 talks about leader election; and it has these words "*Each server will vote for at most one candidate in a
given term, on a first-come-first-served basis (note: Section 5.4 adds an additional restriction on votes).*"

Section 5.4 *"The previous sections described how Raft elects leaders and replicates log entries. However, the mechanisms
described so far are not quite sufficient to ensure that each
state machine executes exactly the same commands in the
same order..."*

Basically if a reader reads the paper section by section, and stops to think after each of them, then the reader will be a bit confused. At least I was :)

As a general conclusion: new term absolute value does not make any difference. It is used to reject older terms. But for actual leader election (and new term being started) it's the state of the log what actually matters.